# Why that high number of all time reviews

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts, review-stats

On Stack Overflow [Low Quality Posts statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats) page I saw a user (Nikola K) who has **7626** all time reviews. I was surprised when noticed that the user is a member for only **7 months**.

Haying in mind that *Low Quality Posts queue* has a daily limit of *20 reviews*, simple calculation as follows `8 months * 31 days * 20 reviews` gives only **4960** possible reviews, which is far less than **7.5k**.

I was wondering if that hight number of reviews for that particular user is because the user has some *special privileges* for reviews in the Low Quality Posts queue or is it just a presentation issue with *all time reviews* or *how long this user is a member for*?

Comment: FYI: [He earned the Steward badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/2279/steward?userid=1494505) in Sep 21.

Comment: Lots of people got that badge on Sep 21, meaning that they had already performed over 1000 reviews in the old review system.

Comment: @BoPersson: Only the suggested edits stats were backfilled for the badges. The new badges didn't exist for quite some time after "Review Beta" started, so some people qualified for it already when it was created on that day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The review limits per day used to be much higher. When the new review system was first started, you were limited to 50 reviews per day in each queue (100 on Stack Overflow). That was reduced to 20 as the queues emptied out and not as many reviewers were needed all at once, in order to preserve vote diversity.

Comment: So that would indicate the limit reduction to 20 items per day was introduced couple of months ago; is that correct?

Comment: @Tom: Back in October sometime I believe.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. Many thanks for your answer!

Comment: There also used to be posts in the queue... (!)